# How to create a cookie with node cookie-session

Tags: node.js, express, cookie-session

I am running a small node app. And I am trying to get it to create a cookie for each visitor, called 'session' that contains - for example - the session id. But I cannot seem to get node to create a cookie through cookie-session. My code so far:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('PATHTOKEY');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('PATHTOKEY');
const credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
const Keygrip = require("keygrip");    

const express = require('express');
const app = express();    

const port = APORTNUMBER;
const secureport = APORTNUMBER;
const helmet = require('helmet');    

const options = {
  dotfiles: 'deny',
  etag: true,
  extensions: ['html', 'htm'],
  index: 'index.html',
  lastModified: true,
  maxAge: 0,
  redirect: true,
  setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
    res.set('x-timestamp', Date.now())
  }
};    

app.use(express.static('public', options), helmet());
```

So far, no problems. But then comes the middleware cookie-session.

```
const session = require('cookie-session');
const expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000); // 1 hour    

app.use( 
  session({
    name: 'session',
    keys: new Keygrip(["MYSECRET1", "MYSECRET2"]),
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      expires: expiryDate
    }
  })
);
```

Above, I've specified the middleware to use these cookie-session parameters, but how do I proceed from here to actually get it to create this cookie?

```
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);    

httpServer.listen(port);
httpsServer.listen(secureport);    

console.log("Node server started");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after trying this myself I manages to successfully use the `cookie-session` middleware. yay

I'm using the middleware like this:

```
app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session', // replace this with your own name to suit your needs
  keys: [ 'your-secret-key-goes-here', 'your-secret-key-goes-here' ]
})
```

About the duplicate values in `keys` option - the docs and related examples always use 2 different keys, despite the TypeScript `@types` lib declares that

> The list of keys to use to sign & verify cookie values. Set cookies
> are always signed with keys[0], while the other keys are valid for
> verification, allowing for key rotation.

So.. I've used only one key.. twice... and it works as excepted

Note that I'm using this middleware before I'm registering the express `app` routes in order for this middleware to take effect before the router is executed (per request)

In each of my routes I can use the middleware using something like this

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  req.session.test = { a: 5, b: 7} // yes - JSON payload are valid :)
})
```

To verify - ensure that your initial request got the following headers

```
Set-Cookie: session=eyJ0ZXN0Ijp7ImEiOjUsImIiOjd9fQ==; path=/; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie: session.sig=D4VVF4XSbBEWXI4b04ZvybAxppw; path=/; secure; httponly
```

This is only an example where the `session` is the name of the cookie as I've defined earlier. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your current code looks right, based also on the documentation @ http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html

I would suggest defining an `app.get` and testing everything with a tool like postman or fidler.

e.g.

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
  // Update views
  req.session.views = (req.session.views || 0) + 1

  // Write response
  res.end(req.session.views + ' views')
})
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did no create any visible cookie when I visit my app through the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to figure out how to work with neither express-cookie nor cookie-session. However, I have been able to create cookies with cookie-parser middleware.

dependency:

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
```

config:

```
const cookieConfig = {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  maxAge: 1800,
  signed: true
};
```

Express:

```
app.use(cookieParser('MYSECRET'));    

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  let cookie = req.cookies.cookieName;
  if (cookie === undefined) {
    let randomNumber=LOGICFORRANDOMNUMBER
    res.cookie('COOKIENAME', randomNumber, cookieConfig);
  };
  next();
});
```